# Kakeya needle problem, change needle to other shapes

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Kakeya needle problem tries to turn a needle through $360^\circ$ in a small set. I am thinking about the problem that changing the needle to other unit-length curves.

I have an initial guess: if the curve's curvature exists everywhere and has the same sign, the set should also be zero measure, otherwise, the set cannot be zero measure.

One simple example is a circular arc, the corresponding circle is the set. That means for a constant curvature curve, the guess is correct.

However, is it possible to construct Besicovitch needle sets for changing curvature curves, e.g. ellipse arc?

Is my guess correct? Does anyone know where to find material on this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by “If connecting the start and goal points of the curve and the 2D area is convex”? You can always connect the points. How does this relate to what area? Also, I am pretty sure that whatever you are suggesting fails for an ellipsis and an ellipsis arc.

Comment: I mean connecting start and goal points with a straight line and we can get a 2D shape. Let me remove area part.

Comment: I think the "L"-shaped curve may be a contradiction. But I am not sure about the ellipsis arc, could I use Besicovitch needle sets for a set construction?